# Looking for nbit adder in c++

Tags: c++

I was trying to build 17bit adder, when overflow occurs it should round off should appear just like int32.

```
eg: In int32 add, If a = 2^31 -1 
int res = a+1
res= -2^31-1
```

Code I tried, this is not working & is there a better way. Do I need to convert decimal to binary & then perform 17bit operation

```
int addOvf(int32_t result, int32_t a, int32_t b)
{  
    int max = (-(0x01<<16))
    int min = ((0x01<<16) -1)
    int range_17bit = (0x01<<17);

    if (a >= 0 && b >= 0 && (a > max - b)) {
        printf("...OVERFLOW.........a=%0d b=%0d",a,b);
    }
    else if (a < 0 && b < 0 && (a < min - b)) {
        printf("...UNDERFLOW.........a=%0d b=%0d",a,b);
    }
   
     result = a+b;
     if(result<min) {
         while(result<min){ result=result + range_17bit; }
     }
     else if(result>min){
         while(result>max){ result=result - range_17bit; }
     }
     return result;
}

int main() 
{
        int32_t res,x,y;
        x=-65536;
        y=-1;
        res =addOvf(res,x,y);
        printf("Value of x=%0d y=%0d res=%0d",x,y,res);
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: start with a 3-bit adder. then work your way up to a 4,5,6,...-bit adder. by the time you'll get to 17, you'll nail it !

Comment: As given, the code won't compile because of some missing semi-colons. Also, why are you passing the variable `result` to the function, only to return it? You probably want to do one or the other, not both, and if you did intend to pass it as an argument, it should probably be passed by reference. When you do pass it, you aren't initializing it first. Finally, is this supposed to be C++ code, or C code? You are consistently using the `printf()` function, which leads me to think this is meant as C code.

Comment: If you don't mind me asking, what is the application for this? Is this just an exercise, or is this part of a larger project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have your constants for max/min `int17` reversed and off by one. They should be

```
max_int17 = (1 << 16) - 1 = 65535
```

and

```
min_int17 = -(1 << 16) = -65536.
```

Then I believe that `max_int_n + m == min_int_n + (m-1)` and `min_int_n - m == max_int_n - (m-1)`, where `n` is the bit count and `m` is some integer in `[min_int_n, ... ,max_int_n]`. So putting that all together the function to treat two int32's as though they are int17's and add them would be like

```
int32_t add_as_int17(int32_t a, int32_t b) {
    static const int32_t max_int17 = (1 << 16) - 1;
    static const int32_t min_int17 = -(1 << 16);
    auto sum = a + b;
    if (sum < min_int17) {
        auto m = min_int17 - sum;
        return max_int17 - (m - 1);
    } else if (sum > max_int17) {
        auto m = sum - max_int17;
        return min_int17 + (m - 1);
    }
    return sum;
}
```

There is probably some more clever way to do that but I believe the above is correct, assuming I understand what you want.

Comment: Thanks a lot!. This worked & I can parameterize this with any value apart from 17.

Comment: yeah it would be easy to make that a template parametrized on the bit count.